# Out of memory allocating 65536 bytes

Tags: qt, compiler-errors

When I try to debug my Qt application I get the following error:

- *out of memory allocating 65536 bytes*  **cc1plus.exe**

I have an .exe File in the qrc resource which is larger than 10 MB.

I tried **QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O0** in my .pro file, but I get still the memory error.

- Qt 4.8.4 static compiled
- Windows 7 x64
- 16 GB RAM

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit what do you mean by 'external Qt Program larger then 10Mb in QRC file'?

Comment: Possibly the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231266/qt-compiling-error-out-of-memory-allocating-134mb-cc1plus-exe-not-found

Comment: the executable file which i include in my qrc is bigger than 10 mb. i think it wont change anything when im use two qrc files for my projekt . but i need the executable in my qt application because its a static compiled standalone software without any dlls.

Comment: @SerYoga So you do not _need_ the executable in the `.qrc` at all, you can simply call it from outside your application.

Comment: yes but if the exe dont exists outside i need a way to generate the executable in the tmp directory and start it.

Comment: @SerYoga You would deploy it where it needs to be like any other dependent file, then start it with `QProcess`.

Comment: @cmannett85 is it possible without creating an installer for my software? I have to deliver only one executable without dlls or other dependencies. THis is the reason why the other executable is implemented in the qrc file becuase i can generate the file if its not exists and the customer dont need to download multiple files like qt dlls or the additional executable. And im not allowed to generate an installer for my software :/.

Comment: and i use  QProcess::startDetached(QDir::tempPath()+"/"+updateFileName+".exe");

Comment: @SerYoga Why can't you use an installer?

Comment: Related (may or may not be a duplicate) - UTF-16 encoded source file: *[Running 'gcc' on C++ source file on Linux gives “cc1plus: out of memory allocating …” error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588296)*