# How to integrate big data files into QT Project (Error: cc1plus.exe out of memory allocating xxx Bytes)?

Tags: c++, qt, file, user-interface, c++11

I want to integrate an audio wave file into an qt c++ project.
The compiler gives this error when trying to open the file
QT Ressoures: cc1plus.exe out of memory allocating Bytes

It is a file with size 40megabyte, which seems to big for the qt ressources.
For more information to the error see this post:
[Qt compiling error: "out of memory allocating 134mb" "cc1plus.exe not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231266/qt-compiling-error-out-of-memory-allocating-134mb-cc1plus-exe-not-found)

Is there a possibilty to integrate big files into an qt project without using the ressources?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have the same issue. How do I solve this ?